# How does Orchard build my solution?

Tags: visual-studio, orchardcms

I'm working on an Orchard solution and, to test the latest code changes, could either build it in Visual Studio, or make a request to the site and Orchard will build it prior to responding.

What mechanism does it use to do this? Is it literally a compiler it calls 'under the hood' somehow? I'm asking because building in my IDE takes considerably longer than allowing Orchard to build as part of handling a request. There is a lot more going on in Visual Studio (my extensions etc.) but still surprised at the difference, and the fact Orchard can even do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Orchard does dynamic compilation of modules when a file that is referenced by the project file is modified, or when the project file is modified.

Comment: Is it also because of this it compiles a lot faster? Because it only (re)compiles changes?